# Generate Unique Random Numbers with Range

Tags: android, random

I am beginner in android.

display random numbers of images, kids have to count number images

for answer generate 4 random choice, code is working fine

but sometimes app get hanged, can't optimize code.

**Generate Answer**

```
int[] answer = new int[4];


    int count=0,random_integer;
    while(count<=3){
        random_integer = r.nextInt((imageCount+2) - (imageCount-2)) + (imageCount-2);
        if(!exists(random_integer,answer)){
            answer[count] = random_integer;
            Log.d("answer","Array " + count + " = " + random_integer);
            count++;
        }
    }

    if(!exists(imageCount,answer)){
        answer[r.nextInt(3 - 0) + 0] = imageCount;
    }
```

**Check Duplicate**

```
public boolean exists(int number, int[] array) {
    if (number == -1)
        return true;

    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (number == array[i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Logcat**

[image: While generating 4 value it stopped]
While generating 4 value it stopped
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you see any errors in logcat ?

Comment: Side note: `(imageCount+2) - (imageCount-2)` is a rather complicated way to write `4`.

Comment: imageCount is not fix that also is Random @Henry

Comment: No matter what `imageCount` is, the answer will always be 4.

Comment: no errors @nimi0112

Comment: if imageCount is 7 , then choice could be 7,9,5,8

if imageCount is 9, then choice could be 10,11,9,7,8

@Henry

Comment: It also may be a device specific error because of low memory available. Try it out on a different device.

Comment: it should work, will device, that why wanted to optimize - also tried in genymotion - same issue @nimi0112

Comment: @MohammediComputers I was talking about the expression `(imageCount+2) - (imageCount-2)`. This is always 4.

Answer (score 1):

The answer array is initialized with zeroes. This means, a `random_integer` of 0 will not be accepted by the `exists` check.

In the case that `imageCount` is 2, the only four possible random answers are 0, 1, 2, 3. Since 0 is not accepted, the while loop will never terminate.

A similar problem appears if `imageCount` is smaller than 2.

Comment: Yes true, just noticed that, if imageCount is greater then 3 it works fine
--- solution for that? please suggest @Henry

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want to achieve. Curently the outcome will always be the 4 numbers in the range `[imageCount-2, image_count+1]` in some order. Is that what you want?